# python shutil copyfile permission error

Tags: python, image, file, permissions, shutil

I am trying to copy an image from one folder to another folder using shutil in python 3.6 windows 10, but am running into permission errors.

I have my source saved as a variable named 'src' which contains

```
src = "C:/Users/marti/AppData/Roaming/vlc/art/artistalbum/artistname/art.jpg"
```

and my destination named 'src' which contains

```
dst = "C:/Users/marti/Desktop/MRL/cover"
```

my file currently imports these things:

```
from shutil import copyfile
from sys import exit
import os
import requests
```

and I am copying the src to the destination using this command:

```
copyfile(src, dst)
```

But when I run this program I am given a permission error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/marti/Desktop/MRL/cover/'
```

even when I'm running CMD as administrator, does anyone know how to edit these permissions for python?

If not I'm open to any other methods which will allow me to copy an image from one folder to another folder, and eventually check if the src string has changed in which case it will delete the image in the dst folder and replace it

Comment: I do not if it is a typo, but you have space characters in your variable `src`. Then, where is the file name in `src`? `src = r"C:/Users/marti/Desktop/MRL/cover/art.jpg"` may be better.

Comment: Yes this was a type thank you, but when I fix it and have the src with no spaces I still get this error message:                                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 39, in <module>
    getInfo()
  File "a.py", line 36, in getInfo
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/marti/Desktop/MRL/cover'

Comment: @MartinBarker Please post the info to your question, and we don't know the temp_loc is what here. can you explain ?

Comment: @aircraft sorry, this was meant to be src, I'm trying to copy the art.jpg file located at src into the folder located at dst

Comment: Try `src = r"C:/Users/marti/Desktop/MRL/cover/art.jpg"`. I mean what do you copy ? `art.jpg` is missing in your current variable `src`. In the name of the method `copyfile` there is the word *file*.

Comment: @Kanak yeah my bad wow I can't believe I made a mistake like that, I fixed the my post so that the src is the source image I want to copy and then dst is the location where I want to copy my image too.

Comment: @MartinBarker Have you tried add `art.jpg` after the existing dst ?

Comment: @aircraft YES that did it, is that just the syntax to python, that if your copying the file to a destination, you need to include the name of the file at the end of the destination?

Comment: Yes it is just that !! Reread my previous comments. I told you exactly that three times. (before you interchanged your `dst` and `src` definitions).

Answer (score 1):

From the [shutil doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html):

> Copy the contents (no metadata) of the file named src to a file named dst and return dst. src and dst are path names given as strings. dst must be the complete target file name; look at shutil.copy() for a copy that accepts a target directory path. If src and dst specify the same file, SameFileError is raised.

You should pay attention the `dst must be the complete target file name`.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue when copying a native file to NAS, but easily solved by replacing `shutil.copyfile` with `shutil.copy`.

---

My previous error messages:

```
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Comment: what is difference bewtween copyfile and copy